# NPM install error - error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac

Tags: node.js, npm

I received the following error while running `npm install`:

```
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! syscall write

npm ERR! write EPROTO 101057795:error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 20
npm ERR! 101057795:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:659:
```

This error seems to be due to an `SSL` failure with the `npm install` command. How can I resolve this issue?